# Cómo decir "Cheeky smile" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, adjetivos, estados-unidos

Estoy buscando una manera de decir "cheeky smile". En mi clase he usado la frase "sonrisa descarada" pero no se si hay alguna manera mejor de decirlo. En termino de dialectos, vivo en los Estados Unidos

I have also found "sonrisa fresca"

Comment: Sonrisa pícara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La traducción más acertada sería ‘sonrisa pícara’ o ‘sonrisa traviesa’.

Utilizar ‘sonrisa descarada’ es bastante acertado también, aunque creo que tendría una connotación ligeramente negativa.
También se puede usar ‘sonrisa insolente’, teniendo esta expresión una connotación más negativa aún que la palabra ‘descarada’.

Comment: Lo busco para describir a algien que me gusta, pues quizas picara o traviesa seria buenos

Answer (score 3):

`Cheeky` puede ser traducido como ser traducido como "insolente", "caradura", "descarado", etc.

`Cheeky smile` puede traducirse de muchas maneras distintas dependiendo del contexto, para favorecer una traducción (palabra) sobre otra.

Tu propuesta de "sonrisa descarada" me parece acertada. "Sonrisa fresca" un poco menos. Si bien "fresco" es sinónimo de insolente o caradura "sonrisa fresca" tiene un poco menos de connotación en ese sentido, ya que "fresco" también es sinónimo de "limpio" o "nuevo" ("Sonrisa fresca" es algo que podrías oír en un anuncio de pasta de dientes, con la connotación de "limpio" y "agradable", más que "descarado").

Answer (score 2):

A mi `cheeky` significa mal intención.  Una `mala sonrisa`.. una `sonrisa traviesa`... una `sonrisa malvada`..

Answer (score 1):

Agrego otras traducciones que servirían en Chile, no estoy seguro de que valgan en USA:

- sonrisa **picarona** (es positiva, implica complicidad en alguna maldad infantil o un doble sentido sexual).
- sonrisa **socarrona** (es negativa, por ejemplo cuando hay desprecio o ironía malintencionada).